# Using SocketsHttpHandler in .NET Core 2.2 and ignoring cert validation

Tags: c#, .net-core, certificate, httpclient, httpclienthandler

With `HttpClientHandler`, we are able to set a server validation callback and return true (by writing it out or using `DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator`). How can I ensure that I bypass this verification also when I switch my `HttpClient` to use `SocketsHttpHandler` after upgrading to .NET Core 2.2? Is this the default? I can't find much information on this topic currently, and I will be deploying to an environment where I'd like to avoid making a breaking change.

Comment: I believe the same option is available under SocketsHttpHandler.SslOptions.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback

Comment: I believe you're correct. I can let you know if this works the same way once I've deployed to production (only env. where I have this issue) in a few days. You can either add this as an answer now or wait till I've verified?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

@djsoteric I had the same exact issue, solved it this way

```
public static HttpClient CreateHttpClient()
{
    var sslOptions = new SslClientAuthenticationOptions
    {
        // Leave certs unvalidated for debugging
        RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; },
    };

    var handler = new SocketsHttpHandler()
    {
        SslOptions = sslOptions,
    };

    return new HttpClient(handler);
}
```